# How to use sum function in SSRS which contains $ sign in revenue amount

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

=CDec(Right(Fields!totalamount.Value,LEN(Fields!totalamount.Value)-1))

My revenue amount is like $120.00, $250.50, etc
How can I add these amounts in SSRS?

Comment: Why they are like that ? What is your data looks like ? Please add what you are trying to do with the your sample data.

Comment: @CoderofCode i have a column named as 'Revenue' which contains amount $120.00, $250.50, etc. I want to add these revenue amount to get the total but it gives me above error. Can you assist?

Comment: Yes but what data you get from database for that column can you post it in the question. Is the `$` comes from the database for it is applied in the report ?

Comment: @CoderofCode yes $ 120.0 comes from CRM database as well. All these revenues are coming from CRM system.

Comment: @CoderofCode I am still getting error. Revenue amount are like $120.00, $485.50, $14.00. How can I add these amount. Tried your function but didn't work out. Can you help me out !

Comment: What error you got ? Can you post it

Comment: @CoderofCode 
The Value expression for the textrun ‘Textbox38.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]’ contains an error: Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: Do one thing put the new column and add the expression as `Right(Field!Yoursomefield.Value,LEN(Field!Yoursomefield.Value)-1)` and post what you get.

Comment: @CoderofCode I got just the amount without $ sign. i.e.120.00, 485.00. But still it gives error as "Conversion from string "$‎14.00" to type 'Decimal' is not valid". How will i sum ?

Comment: Now try this in new column `CDec(Right(Field!Yoursomefield.Value,LEN(Field!Yoursomefield.Value)-1))`

Comment: @CoderofCode still same error "Conversion from string "$‎14.00" to type 'Decimal' is not valid". Not even amount is displayed. It shows as #Error in report

Comment: Clear the error box and post what expression you are trying in question.

Comment: @CoderofCode can you suggest anything regarding this...the amount which is coming from CRM is currency field. how would i sum the revenue amount?

Comment: The answer given should work if what you are saying is right

Comment: @CoderofCode Hey finally it worked...in CRM we have 2 different fields (totalamount & totalamountvalue). Here i need to select totalamountvalue for doing any arithmetic operations. On the contrary i was selecting totalamount which was wrong. Thanks a lot for your time.